# How to get the minimal of a LocalDateTime property in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I get the minimal of a `LocalDateTime` property. I tried `min(v.datetime)` and it gives me an error: `Only boolean, numeric and string values are allowed in MIN and MAX aggregations`"

Answer (score 0):

Temporal types still don't support `min`/`max` functions. There is an open issue in the Memgraph repository. (https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/1422).

As a workaround, you can use [collections module from MAGE library](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/collections#max). Here is an example how to use it:

```
CREATE (:Person {birthday: date("1947-07-30")});
CREATE (:Person {birthday: date("1948-07-30")});

MATCH (n:Person)
WITH collect(n.birthday) AS birthdays
RETURN collections.max(birthdays);
```